# Playing AAC (ADTS) file with Netstream Appendbytes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, aac, netstream

I want to know if it's really possible to play an AAC (ADTS header) file with Netstream.appendbytes. I'm talking about files that end `.aac` not AAC audio inside M4A or MP4 containers.

I'm aware Netstream can't parse ADTS headers etc so I already have a class for parsing the data and gives back correct info such as channels, bitrates, framelengths etc.

**Putting this together gives silence:** Make FLV header (+ append) **->>** Make audio tag header (+ append) **->>** now append with raw/headerless AAC payload (frame 1) + update previous tag size **->>** Make new audio tag for next AAC frame & append **->>** raw/headerless payload append (frame 2) and so on until track end.

Can someone please clarify:

- In the FLV tag we put extra byte to specify whether Raw or Sequenced AAC type. If I have removed the 7 byte header and left with only data up the next frame/SyncWord. I assume its Raw but I get silence whichever setting I choose. Should I be considering anything else (ie an additional function depending on type?)
- Should AAC header bytes exist in some data at some point sent to the Appendbytes command? Even if I already set FLV tag to Raw AAC audio?
- Do all AAC files hold 1024 samples per frame regardless of channels or should I multiply 1024 by channels number? I ask because I need this for correct duration calculation and noticed when testing MP3s that I get silence if duration or framelengths are wrong.

I have a lot of questions and a lot research (AAC specs, FLV specs etc) but nothing is helping and there is some confused info on the net (well they don't always speak from an AS3 perspective..). I guess **I just need to know it's definitely possible** rather than keep on blindly against a technical limitation

PS: I have succesfully played .MP3 audio files with AppendBytes and now changed the process to accomodate AAC (ie: parsing 7 byte header not 4 byte header etc. More to it than that ofcos). Thanks for reading and hope someone out there can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I meant to answer this a while back...

Working Demo.. [[ A very basic demo of AAC file playback ]](http://www.swfcabin.com/swf-files/1411416171.swf) (see below if you need some test AAC file)

I can happily confirm that it's 100% possible to play an `.aac` audio file using NetStream.
So to clarify my own questions:

- You need **both** AAC types mentioned at first to kickstart the AAC decoder then afterwards you can do the usual **FLV tag with AAC type: Raw + Raw AAC data (no ADTS header)** and continue as such until track end.
- Nope. No ADTS bytes should be sent to the Netstream decoder.
- Yes every AAC frame contains 1024 samples and each frame is equal to 23.21 milisecs  (around 44 frames for 1 second of audio). Channel settings are irrelevant.

The image below illustrates **the process**. As you can see after the FLV header & metadata there is tags for BOTH types at first but afterwards its AAC type raw for the rest of the way. No ADTS means remove the 7 byte header from each AAC frame and shove what's left into  FLV tags. I made one FLV audio tag per AAC frame (easier to deal with seeking & timestamps etc)...

[image]

After analysing a test FLV made with `FFMPEG` inside a Hex editor, I understood to use both settings. I don't how they figured out you needed ***both*** instead of ***either one or other*** like the FLV Specs (ver 10.1) was suggesting. I bow my head to the genius of those guys & girls.

I was stuck because of this: 
[image]

The "Process" image at top is enough for those who know `netstream.appendbytes` to get on with it:

If you need some test audio files...

AAC Loop test 1: (credits: Mark "45" King) - http://goo.gl/U7IuWe 
AAC Loop test 2: (credits: U.T.F.O) - http://goo.gl/W8ieJd 
AAC Extended test: (credits: Enya) - http://goo.gl/EVCy4X

Comment: Code share will be posted asap but if you need playback on mobile you can try the : **[Fresh Planet AAC Player ANE](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-AACPlayer)**

Comment: That link is broken and redirected to 18++ website lol