# Shoutcast aacplus streaming with As3

Tags: actionscript-3, shoutcast

i want a flash player for shoutcast servers. if shoutcast's content type is mpeg, codes is working. But if shoutcast's content type is aacp,  codes not working. 
Codes;

```
var channel:SoundChannel;
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
sound.load(new URLRequest("http://yonradyo.radyolarburada.com:8020/;"));
channel = sound.play();
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Most folks wrap their AAC streams in FLV to get around the Flash streaming problems.  I can't say definitively if your method is possible or not, but since I've never seen anyone do it this way, I'm guessing it isn't.  See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/22923419/362536

Comment: @Brad You're right that `sound.load` won't decode AAC. It's not even meant for MP3 live streams just audio files but y'no.. not many notice the "STREAM" in `NetStream` & think A-ha!! In my own question I wanted to play AAC files to make a multi-format audio player with playlist. Radio was not my concern there.

Comment: @Dursun.. The answer given works. I've tested and you should accept it as the correct one. Just say if you're stuck. PS: Test in a browser only

Answer (score 2):

The Project Thunder Snow (https://code.google.com/p/project-thunder-snow/) is not so fresh, but still working solution for playing aac/aacp streams on PC (but not on mobile platform).

The page https://code.google.com/p/project-thunder-snow/wiki/NBaccPlayer contains a code example simple enough.